# Compare two files contents and create a new output file, preserving some structure

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have two large text files containing a list of dependencies.

The first file contains a list of dependencies in a project sorted by service a small snippet of the file looks like this:

project_dependencies.txt:

```
------------- Dependencies for: Service1 -------------
org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.16.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.16.RELEASE
------------- Dependencies for: Service2 -------------
org.jongo:jongo:1.4.0
org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0
------------- Dependencies for: Service3-------------
junit:junit:4.12
org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.16.RELEASE
...
```

The second one contains a list of dependencies approved by my company. It looks similar but without the services. Here is a snippet:

approved_dependencies.txt:

```
...
com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.1
com.google.code.findbugs:bcel:2.0.1
com.google.code.findbugs:bcel-findbugs:6
com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:3.0.1
com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs-ant:2.0.1
com.google.code.findbugs:jFormatString:2.0.1
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
com.google.code.p.arat:rat-lib:0.5.1
org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.16.RELEASE
...
```

I'm looking for a bash command, or even an `awk` script, that could compare these two files and basically output a file that looks very much like the first one (project_dependencies.txt) but only contains dependencies that arein the second file but are still sorted by service. I have been attempting to do this with `grep` but haven't yet found a solution. What can I use?

Just to make it more clear, here is an example snippet from the desired output file:

```
...
------------- Dependencies for: Service3 -------------
org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.16.RELEASE
------------- Dependencies for: Service4 -------------
com.google.code.findbugs:bcel:2.0.1
com.google.code.findbugs:bcel-findbugs:6
------------- Dependencies for: Service5-------------
com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1
com.google.code.p.arat:rat-lib:0.5.1
...
```

The actual number if dependencies under each service are not realistically represented in this snippet for sake of brevity. All I'm trying to display here is that dependencies that were not in `approved_dependencies.txt` were removed from the original list and that the continuation of services (in this case Service4 and service5) only contain dependencies from the approved dependency snippet.

Please let me know if I've left anything out, was too ambiguous, or need any clarification in the comments.

Comment: What is missing is the logic that provides any correlation between `Dependencies for: Service4` and the line in `approved_dependencies.txt` and why `..."Service4"` has only one entry while `"...Service5"` contains two, etc.. and why the last line in `approved_dependencies.txt` is shown as the first line under `..."Service4"`. Sewing the files together is no problem, but you have to provide the logic for "How" to do it.

Comment: In addition to David's comments, please add what code/logic you have tried so far.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've made an edit in hopes to satisfy these requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  requirements seem to lend themself to a simple application of grep:

```
grep -F -f approved_dependencies.txt -e ---- project_dependencies.txt
```

- `-F` - search for fixed strings rather than regexp
- `-f file` - look for strings listed in `file`
- `-e ----` - also look for lines with multiple hyphens (or could use `'Dependencies for:'` or somesuch, if you want to be more specific)

Answer (score 1):

Your sample output contains services that aren't in your sample input, which makes testing hard, but maybe:

```
$ awk -F: 'NR == FNR { deps[$1,$2] = $3; next }
           $0 ~ /^---/ { print }
           ($1,$2) in deps && deps[$1,$2] == $3 { print }' approved_dependencies.txt project_dependencies.txt
------------- Dependencies for: Service1 -------------
org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.16.RELEASE
------------- Dependencies for: Service2 -------------
------------- Dependencies for: Service3-------------
org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.16.RELEASE
```